# Disaster recovery set up for Azure Data Factory service

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I just added azure data factory service to my subscription. During the setup I was able to select only one region, what happens if disaster happens in this region? How does ADF guarantees high availability?
Do we need to wait till recovery or is there any similar setup like in ADLS2(GRS & RA-GRS).

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: yes, thanks for your answer. I looked into the Integration runtimes link and configured multiple nodes in self-hosted IR for High availability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No statements of Disaster Recovery could be found in the ADF official document.Based on my researching,ADF only provides cloud-based data integration work flow, the DR is affected by the supported data stores in ADF actually. I provide some clues for your reference:

1.The statement of Location option when you create ADF:

[image]

2.High availability for Azure Integration Runtime,it is affected by DU setting(allocation of compute resources):https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-features#data-integration-units

3.High availability for Self-Hosted Integration Runtime,it could be better if you create multiple nodes in  the on-premise environment:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime#high-availability-and-scalability